# Please verify my solutions to some questions on Cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

> $A.\; \int_{|z| = 1} \frac{e^z}{z^n}dz$
>
> $B. \; \int_{|z| = 2} \frac{dz}{z^2+1}$
>
> $C.\;\int_{|z| = 1}\frac{\cos(z^2)}{z}dz $

Answer $A.$

if $n \leq 0$, then the integrand is analytic on and inside the circle $|z| =1$, hence, the given contour integral will be $0$.

if $n \geq 1, $  then $f(z) = e^z$ is analytic on and inside $|z|=1$ therefore using extension of Cauchy Integral formula we get

$$\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{e^z}{z^n}dz = [\frac{(n-1)!}{2i\pi}\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{e^z}{z^n}dz] \times \frac{2i\pi}{(n-1)!} = \frac{2i\pi}{(n-1)!} f^{(n-1)}(0) = \frac{2i\pi}{(n-1)!}\;\;$$

Answer B.

$$\; \int_{|z| = 2} \frac{dz}{z^2+1} = \int_{|z| = 2} \frac{dz}{(z-i)(z+i)} = \frac{1}{2i} \int_{|z| = 2} (\frac{1}{z-i} - \frac{1}{z+i})dz = \frac{1}{2i}(2i\pi - 2i\pi) =0 $$

Answer C.

Let $f(z) = \cos(z^2)$ which is analytic on and inside $|z|=1$, then using Cauchy Integral formula
$$\int_{|z| = 1}\frac{\cos(z^2)}{z}dz  = 2i\pi f(0) = 2i\pi$$

Are my solutions correct?

Comment: They are all correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you very much